# apt-mirror and fresh install

Tags: 14.04, apt-mirror

I've set up a local mirror of Ubuntu 14.04 server using apt-mirror - this is working fine.
However, how to I get a fresh install of 14.04 server to use my mirror during the installation process? I can't see any option there to change the mirror it uses.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the normal ISOs, which expect to use the files included on the ISO when installing, [the minimal install ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) is designed to download packages during the installation, so it allows you to choose which mirror to use:

1. Right after choosing your hostname, the `Choose a mirror of the Ubuntu archive` menu will appear.
2. Go to the very top of the list and select `enter information manually`:

   [image: Choose a mirror of the Ubuntu archive]
3. Enter the hostname of your mirror.
4. Enter the mirror directory.
5. If you're using one, enter any proxy you're using to reach the mirror.
6. When it, much later, the `Software selection` menu comes up, choose which servers you want, ensuring that `Basic Ubuntu server` at the very bottom of the list is also selected:

   [image: Software selection]